# UNIX Sed Command to Replace double quote " with 2 single quote ''

Tags: shell, unix, sed, tr

My file has record like this

```
 Nitin "Nick" Patel
```

I want to replace double quote with 2 single quotes:

```
 Nitin ''Nick'' Patel
```

I tried the command

```
sed -i "s/\Nitin "Nick" Patel/Nitin ''Nick''Patel/g" test1.csv
```

but unfortunately it is not replacing anything.
Please advise.

Answer (score 2):

```
sed "s/\"/''/g" File
Nitin ''Nick'' Patel
```

Or (depending upon exact requirement, previous one will replace all `"` with 2 `'`):

```
sed "s/Nitin \"Nick\" Patel/Nitin ''Nick'' Patel/g" File
Nitin ''Nick'' Patel
```

Answer (score 0):

Mixing single and double quotes on the command line requires care.  That's probably why you were asked to do it.  With your command line:

```
sed -i "s/\Nitin "Nick" Patel/Nitin ''Nick''Patel/g" test1.csv
```

the shell actually removes the embedded doubles quotes (and in fact `sed` doesn't see any of the double quotes) — it is as though you wrote:

```
sed -i "s/\Nitin Nick Patel/Nitin ''Nick''Patel/g" test1.csv
```

I'm not sure why you put a backslash before the N of `Nitin` in the search string, either.

There are multiple ways to do the requisite substitution, including:

```
sed -i.bak "s/Nitin \"Nick\" Patel/Nitin ''Nick'' Patel/g" test1.csv

sed -i.bak 's/Nitin "Nick" Patel/Nitin '\'\''Nick'\'\'' Patel/g' test1.csv

sed -i.bak -f script.sed test1.csv
```

where `script.sed` contains:

```
s/Nitin "Nick" Patel/Nitin ''Nick'' Patel/g
```

Answer (score 0):

One may try:

```
sed -i "s/\x22/\x27\x27/g" test1.csv
```

Comment: Does that need `\x27\x27` to replace one double quote with two single quotes?  Does it not also edit `He said, "Don't!"` so that it becomes either `He said, 'Don't!'` or `He said, ''Don't!''`, whereas the sample was explicitly dealing with `Nitin "Nick" Patel` only?

Comment: @Jonathan You are right. Here \x22 is hex code for one double quote and \x27 is hex code for one single code